# Some of the webp images not loading Magento 2

Tags: magento2, media-images

Some of the webp images not loading. Showing 404 error. How to remove this format in Magento 2.

Comment: Are you using any third party modules for image optimization or page speed optimization module?

Comment: No. I didnt use anything. In mozilla its working.. |But in chrome its showing 404

Comment: So are you directly using webp images for products

Comment: No. Its automatically changed. I did basic optimization only. I want to remove that. How it possible?

Comment: Without the help of any modules or any customisations in server side the images won't be changed to webp format so what change you have done?

Comment: Okay I will check it.  My image link is like this. <Domain>/pub/media/wysiwyg/ximg2.jpg.pagespeed.ic.RgYurD9NtV.webp

Comment: is that possible by any server configuration?

Comment: It seems that you have enabled Google Pagespeed Module in your server. Please verify it by seeing in your browser network tab. Check the site header where you will find like this "X-Mod-Pagespeed: 1.13.35.2-0". Can you please confirm whether you have enabled this?

Comment: Loaded image format is like this <img src="<DOMAIN>/pub/media/wysiwyg/footerlogo.png" alt="" data-pagespeed-url-hash="1449569927" data-pagespeed-onload="pagespeed.CriticalImages.checkImageForCriticality(this);" onload="var elem=this;if (this==window) elem=document.body;elem.setAttribute('data-pagespeed-loaded', 1)" data-pagespeed-loaded="1">

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92456/discussion-between-raj-mohan-r-and-soofz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have enabled **Google Page Speed Module** in your **Nginx Server**. You can disable the images from converting to webp by editing the page speed module configurations in `/usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` editing `pagespeed EnableFilters convert_jpeg_to_webp` to `pagespeed DisableFilters convert_jpeg_to_webp`. Once it is done your images will not be converted to webp.